# Give different names for new windows created in python gui, every time a button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code where a new window is generated everytime a button is pressed using `Toplevel()`. What happens is every time I press a button the windows are created with a single name (new_window_2), In that case i am not able to control each window correctly. So i want to create windows with different names everytime the button is pressed.

code:

```
def create(event):
    new_window_2 = Toplevel(window)
    new_window_2.geometry('500x600')
    owner_comb_data = tk.StringVar()    
    owner_combo = ttk.Combobox(new_window_2,width = 20,textvariable = owner_comb_data, values = owners)
    owner_combo.set("OWNER")
    owner_combo.grid(column = 1, row =1, padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: No No....I was not referring to the title of the window...I was referring to new_window_2(ie., the name of the widget)

Comment: ***referring to `new_window_2` ... the name of the widget***: This is the name of the variable, every `tkinter` widget has a `name=` attribute also. You have to use a sequence data type like `list` or `dict`.

Comment: Can you please show me a small example using sequence data type(list)

Comment: Take the tour [Dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and [Lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).